# Angular error in IE: Unable to set nodeValue of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

**TL;DR**

See [this Code Pen](http://codepen.io/djskinner/pen/GJKoyO) that demonstrates the error in IE. Replacing `<div>{{item.name}}</div>` with `<div>&nbsp;{{item.name}}</div>` fixes the issue. Why?

**Full Question**

I have a `parent` directive that uses `transclude: true`. Within the `parent` template there is a `repeater` directive that transcludes the contents by dynamically creating an `ng-repeat` and compiling it such that the transcluded contents is repeated.

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="ieTest">
    <parent>
        <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    </parent>
</div>
```

The `parent` directive:

```
.directive('parent', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function() {
      var ctrl = this;

      $timeout(function($timeout) {
        ctrl.items = [{ 
          name: 'One'
        }, {
          name: 'Two'
        }, {
          name: 'Three'
        }];        
      }, 1000);

      $timeout(function($timeout) {
        ctrl.items = [{ 
          name: 'Five'
        }, {
          name: 'Two'
        }, {
          name: 'Three'
        }, {
          name: 'Four'
        }];        
      }, 2000);    
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<section><div repeater></div></section>',
    link: function() {
      // This is where fancy stuff happens that is not relevant to the issue
    }
  }
})
```

The `repeater` directive:

```
.directive('repeater', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^parent',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl, transclude) {
      transclude(function(clone) {
        element.append(clone);
      });

      // Simplified for the test case but this ng-repeat expression is dynamically generated in reality
      element.attr('ng-repeat', 'item in ctrl.items');
      element.removeAttr('repeater');

      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  }
})
```

**The problem:**

In Internet Explorer if the transcluded contents is like `<div>{{item.name}}</div>` then there will be an error and the transcluded contents will not be repeated / displayed. To avoid this error I have discovered that adding some simple content that is always present inside the element such as `<div>&nbsp;{{item.name}}</div>` will prevent the error from occuring. Why is this and how do I avoid it?

I've created a reduced test case of the issue [here](http://codepen.io/djskinner/pen/GJKoyO). If you run it in IE10 you should notice that nothing happens after 1s and 2s and there will be `TypeError: Unable to set property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference`
 errors in the console. However if you replace `<div>{{item.name}}</div>` with `<div>&nbsp;{{item.name}}</div>` or anything such as `<div>X{{item.name}}</div>` then it seems to work without issue.

I'm wondering if the issue is with me having to remove the `repeater` attribute and recompile the `repeater` directive to create the `ng-repeat`. Perhaps there is a better way to achieve this?

I'm seeing this problem on IE10 and IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this issue myself in IE. While I don't know why it happens I did find a workaround by using ng-bind instead of the curly braces. Hope this helps.

```
<div ng-bind='item.name'></div>
```